# Electric commander - Set a property based on the status of the status of a step

Tags: build-process, dynamic-properties, electric-cloud

I have an ecloud procedure which has few steps in it. I want to set the value of a property based on the status of the step after its completion.
E.g
Procedure P1
has steps

```
S1 - Runs a command
S11 - Set a property value based on the status of S1
S2 - Runs a command
S12 - Set a property value based on the status of S2
```

Any pointer is appreciated.
If I can set the property value in S1 and S2 in that same step then i dont need S11 and S12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way I achieved this is by checking the outcome of step S1 in S11

S11 will have a run condition $[/javascript ('$[/myJob/jobSteps/S1/outcome]' == 'success')]

and in the S11 command we can set the property ectool setProperty /myProject/TestProperties/S1 success